# LibGDX - How to maintain a background process

Tags: process, notifications, libgdx

The game I want to deveop should have a small constantly running background process, that can, for example send notifications, even if the main game window is closed. Is this possible in LibGDX?
Another question would be, how I can pass arguments to the application? In case of the desktop client, it's obviously the "String[] args"-thing in the static main, but what about android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This libGDX page](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific) shows you how to interface your code in platform specific ways. In Android, you would set up a service, and on a PC, you'd have another process running.

If you want to pass the program arguments to your game, you can have your core class take an argument in its constructor in the form of a `String[]`.

Right now you have something like

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
   new LwjglApplication(new Main(), cfg);
}
```

But you can change it to be

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
   new LwjglApplication(new Main(args), cfg);
}
```

The link I posted suggests using an `Interface` for good abstraction if you're going to get more complicated than this.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you could run your background process as a remote [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). If you scroll down to the Remote Messenger Service Sample it should give you some useful pointers.

There is also a developer guide for services [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).